# java.lang.NullPointerException for WebView.getFavicon() saving to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap

I was trying to add the favicon of a webpage to a sqlite database, but I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when trying to save the favicon to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` via `Bitmap.compress`.

There is my code fragment:

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getFavicon(); 
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, byteArrayBitmapStream);
    byte[] bArray = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
    String[] comments = new String[] {view.getUrl()};
    String[] commentss = new String[] {view.getTitle()};
    int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(1);
    try{
     mySQLiteAdapter.insert(bArray, commentss[nextInt], comments[nextInt]);
    }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you taking into consideration the fact that not all web pages have a favicon?  That would definitely make your bitmap null.

Comment: For google isn't favicon???

Comment: Are you waiting until the page has finished loading all resources to get the favicon?

Comment: Do not ASK if google has a favicon, `verify` whether view.getFavIcon() is null via the debugger. If it is, the rest of the code you posted is irrelevant and only obfuscates the problem.